# jQuery.Deferred exception: .... What could it be due too?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

So I've recently upgrade my project to jQuery 3.x and I don't know if it is due to that or not but a [plugin](https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard) I was using before do not work anymore telling me :

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).bootstrapWizard is not a function
>   TypeError: $(...).bootstrapWizard is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (http://agencedevoyage.app:8000/alacarte:653:22)
>       at j (http://agencedevoyage.app:8000/js/base.js:2:29588)
>       at k (http://agencedevoyage.app:8000/js/base.js:2:29902) undefined

I do not understand what this error mean actually. I'v looked to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) of this method but still can't understand why suddenly there is a change of comportement.

You can have a glance of the error [there](http://www.agencedevoyage.com/alacarte)

Any help would be gladly appreciate.

Comment: You have issue server side. Try to fix error former to this warning you have posted

Comment: @A.Wolff Well I do find the function `bootstrapWizzard` in the page on the head of the document if this is what you meant.

Comment: My console said for that file: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`. So if browser cannot load it, it cannot work client side

Comment: @A.Wolff Ok this is fixed but actually a minified version of this file was include in the head. The one you couldn't reach was the test version.

Comment: Baldrani, isit solved? If it's solved can you explain what is the reason and how you solve it? I have the same issue but I do not know how to fix it and need help. Thank you

Comment: @Joe.L Yeah, I think it was due to a change of property lie `.prop('xx')` being `.attr('xx')` or something like this. I don't really recall it's way behind if you can link me something I'll give a glance. If it can help you this is the js of the page where I was having my problem http://pastebin.com/Y8LcRbXT

Comment: Thanks for your kindness Baldrani, but I got the issue resolved. In my case it is caused by including two different version of jquery.

Comment: @Joe.L Glad you worked out your case :).